# Fine-Uploader in depth information on the use of Azure Blob Storage through python flask

Tags: python, azure, file-upload, azure-blob-storage, fine-uploader

I'm in need of in-depth information (code samples would be greatly appreciated) regarding the process of configuring fine-uploader in order to work with Azure Blob Storage.

Currently I am facing issues understanding the control flow and overall behavior of fine-uploader. I have reviewed the docs in the fine-uploader website but I require further information described without knowledge assumptions.

As of now the architecture of my solution is as following:

My solution consists of a server (SRV), a client (CL) and the azure blob storage container (AC). What I'd like to do is to enable the CL to upload a jpg file to the AC, in order to do so i am currently in the phase of providing the CL with a SAS signature for the blob storage container.

I was unable to do so currently ( I assume this could be not implemented correctly). The handler for the GET request from the fine-uploader is as following:

```
@login_required
@app.route('/sas', methods=['GET'])
def sas():
    container_name = '/asilverman/picdepot/'
    sas = SharedAccessSignature(account_name=app.config['AZURE_ACCOUNT'],account_key=app.config['AZURE_KEY'])
    access_policy = AccessPolicy()
    access_policy.start =   '2015-08-22T21:00:00Z'   #(datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=-120)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') #T%H:%M:%SZ
    access_policy.expiry =  '2015-08-25T21:00:00Z'   #(datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=120)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
    access_policy.permission = 'w'
    sap = SharedAccessPolicy(access_policy)
    sas_token = sas.generate_signed_query_string(container_name, 'c', sap)
    return request.args['bloburi'] + '?' + sas_token
```

My Primary Blob Service Endpoint is: https://asilverman.blob.core.windows.net/

The name of the container I wish to store the picture files in is : picdepot

My fine-uploader is configured as following:

```
var uploader = new qq.azure.FineUploader({

        debug: true,
        element: document.getElementById("fine-uploader"),
        request: {
            endpoint: 'https://asilverman.blob.core.windows.net/picdepot'
        },
        cors: {
            //all requests are expected to be cross-domain requests
            expected: true,
            sendCredentials: true

        },
        signature: {
            customHeaders: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true},
            endpoint: '/sas'
        },
        uploadSuccess: {
            endpoint: ''
        },
        scaling: {
            sendOriginal: false,

            sizes: [
                {name: "", maxSize: 800}
            ]
        },
        validation: {
            allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png']
        }

    });
```

My CORS configuration is as following:

```
    Storage Account: https://asilverman.blob.core.windows.net/
Cors.CorsRules.Count         : 1
corsRule[index]              : 0
corsRule.AllowedHeaders      : Content-Type
corsRule.AllowedHeaders      : Access-Control-Allow-Origin
corsRule.AllowedHeaders      : x-ms-*
corsRule.AllowedMethods      : Get, Put, Delete
corsRule.AllowedOrigins      : *
corsRule.ExposedHeaders      : Access-Control-Allow-Origin
corsRule.MaxAgeInSeconds     : 432000
DefaultServiceVersion        : 2013-08-15
HourMetrics.MetricsLevel     : None
HourMetrics.RetentionDays    :
HourMetrics.Version          : 1.0
Logging.LoggingOperations    : None
Logging.RetentionDays        :
Logging.Version              : 1.0
MinuteMetrics.MetricsLevel   : None
MinuteMetrics.RetentionDays  :
MinuteMetrics.Version        : 1.0
New Properties:    
Cors.CorsRules.Count         : 1
corsRule[index]              : 0
corsRule.AllowedHeaders      : *
corsRule.AllowedMethods      : Get, Put, Delete
corsRule.AllowedOrigins      : *
corsRule.ExposedHeaders      : *
corsRule.MaxAgeInSeconds     : 432000
DefaultServiceVersion        : 2013-08-15
HourMetrics.MetricsLevel     : None
HourMetrics.RetentionDays    :
HourMetrics.Version          : 1.0
Logging.LoggingOperations    : None
Logging.RetentionDays        :
Logging.Version              : 1.0
MinuteMetrics.MetricsLevel   : None
MinuteMetrics.RetentionDays  :
MinuteMetrics.Version        : 1.0
```

Comment: Please update your question to include one _specific_ problem you are having. For example: "My SAS endpoint is failing to sign the request. I am seeing the following message: ..."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I was unable to do so currently ( I assume this could be not implemented correctly).

```
return request.args['bloburi'] + '?' + sas_token
```

@asilveman, it would be better if you can provide the output of this implementation, based on my understanding, the standard format of URL is:

```
storage_url+container_name + '/' + blob_name+'?'+qry_string
```

while qry_string here is a shared access signature url we need to generate.

Code snippet for your reference

```
from azure.storage import AccessPolicy
 from azure.storage.sharedaccesssignature import (
 SharedAccessPolicy,
 SharedAccessSignature,
 )

 DEV_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME ="xxxxx"
 DEV_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY ="xxxxx"
 CONTAINER_NAME='xxxxx'
 STORAGE_URL = 'xxxxx'

 def generate_signature_blob(dev_storage_account_name,dev_storage_account_key,container_name):
 sas = SharedAccessSignature(account_name=dev_storage_account_name,account_key=dev_storage_account_key)
 accss_plcy = AccessPolicy()
 accss_plcy.expiry = '2016-10-12'
 accss_plcy.permission = 'w'
 sap = SharedAccessPolicy(accss_plcy)
 sasToken = sas.generate_signed_query_string(container_name,'container',sap)
 return sas._convert_query_string(sasToken).replace("container","c")
```

Generates shared access signature url:

```
qry_string = generate_signature_blob(DEV_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME,DEV_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY,CONTAINER_NAME)
```

In Python project, you can leverage urllib2 to make a PUT request like this
import urllib2

```
def put_blob(storage_url,container_name, blob_name,qry_string,x_ms_blob_type):
 opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler)
 request = urllib2.Request(storage_url+container_name + '/' + blob_name+'?'+qry_string, data='Hello World!!')
 request.add_header('x-ms-blob-type', x_ms_blob_type)
 request.get_method = lambda: 'PUT'
 opener.open(request)
```

Then uploading a blob to Azure storage via calling:

```
put_blob(STORAGE_URL,CONTAINER_NAME,"sample.jpg",qry_string,"BlockBlob")
```

You may also want to refer to a [good guidance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azureossds/archive/2015/03/30/uploading-files-to-azure-storage-using-sas-shared-access-signature.aspx) that created by Prashanth, please feel free to let us know if you have any further concerns.